# GridGain: An application which uses Gridgain

Tags: hbase, gridgain

I'm planning to do a project for the below specified use-cases. I would like to know, if Gridgain is best suited.

1. Frontend: A Web based application, typically a Dashboard for report generation
2. Backend: Data stored in HBase

So to fetch data from HBase based on some values, load the data to a middle layer (GridGain).

The business logic part will query the middle layer (Gridgain) in order to generate the reports.

Is this usecase be used to make the application?

Is suitable APIs available for the same?

Answer (score 0):

GridGain should work well in this scenario. You can load data from HBase into GridGain in several ways:

1. Use `GridDataLoader` to bulk-load HBase data into GridGain. Then reload it every so often to make sure that GridGain gets the latest changes.
2. Implement `GridCacheStore` to allow GridGain to have read-through and write-through behavior with HBase. This way, whenever some data is accessed and it is not in cache, GridGain will automatically load it from HBase.

Here are the examples shipped with the product:

- [CacheDataLoaderExample](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/CacheDataLoaderExample.java)
- [CacheStoreLoadDataExample](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/store/CacheStoreLoadDataExample.java)

Comment: By the way, the approach above is using standard [GridGain Data Fabric](http://gridgain.com/products/in-memory-data-fabric/) download, not the [GridGain Hadoop Accelerator](http://gridgain.com/products/hadoop-accelerator/).

Comment: So what all changes need to be made, while using GridGain Hadoop Accelerator?

Comment: With Hadoop Accelerator you are plugging GridGain into Hadoop, so you should be able to continue using Hadoop standard APIs.